# ASP.NET MVC 3 - ViewBag property provides no IntelliSense

Tags: intellisense, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I recently installed ASP.NET MVC 3 via web platform installer. I don't have the intellisense support for ViewBag in Razor view. Intellisense works fine with model in Razor view. I tried to rebuild solution, disable ReSharper... but I couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `ViewBag` property is typed as `dynamic`, which means that there is no IntelliSense.

`ViewBag` is an alias/alternative syntax for accessing the `ViewData` dictionary. The two following lines of code are equivalent:

```
ViewBag.Message = "My message";
ViewData["Message"] = "My message";
```

`ViewBag` offers a slightly terser syntax than `ViewData`. Also notice that accessing `ViewData` using string keys also provides no IntelliSense, so you don't really lose any functionality.

One last note is that `ViewBag` and `ViewData` use the same backing storage, so that setting a property using one method makes it available using the other method:

```
ViewBag.Message = "My message";
string message = ViewData["Message"];
// message is now "My message"
```

Comment: Visual Studio shows a red line under `ViewBag`, which looks like an error, very annoying, is there any setting to disable it.

Comment: Same problem as with Eric Yin, in the Views, red marks under ViewBag and HTML.TextBoxFor(), etc... errors says a reference is missing, but which one?

Answer (score 9):

Adding to marcind's answer of the ViewBag being dynamic:

If you want intellisense, then you're going to have to pass in a strongly typed object and then in your view, you can set:`@model Namespace.YourModel` which will give you intellisense when you try to do `@Model.Property`